# How in videojs play recorded video?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this library for recording video on browser https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record

I assumne this is popular library, but how can I play recorded video after finishing on browser?
On "**finishRecord**" event I have recorded data as Blob type but what next?

UPDATE

```
player.on('finishRecord', function() {
// the blob object contains the recorded data that
// can be downloaded by the user, stored on server etc.

//Here i want to play recorded video in some video html tag

//player.record().saveAs({'video': 'my-video-file-name.webm'});
console.log('finished recording: ', player.recordedData);
```

});

**SOLVED**

```
var vsrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(player.recordedData);

var video = document.getElementById('myVideoPlayer');

video.src = vsrc;
video.autoplay = true;

video.play();
```

Comment: Please provide some source code just to show what you've tried and what you have not tried?

Comment: Did you tried  `player.start()` ?

Comment: I updated question

Comment: If it's solved, you should post it as answer and mark it as accepted.